# C++ move guarantees during map insertion

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, unordered-map

I have a code snippet which looks somewhat like this:

```
std::unordered_map<FooId, Foo> fooMap;
Foo foo1(..);
fooMap.emplace(foo1.id(), std::move(foo1));
```

Is the emplace safe, i.e. does the C++ language standard guarantee that `foo1.id()` is invoked before `std::move(foo1)`?

Comment: @RonTang: It's not useless, it allows `emplace` to move rather than copy.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks ,I mistaken Foo foo1(...) as a fuction  ,foo1() return rvalue..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question: `std::move` does nothing, so it doesn't matter that the function arguments aren't evaluated in a specified order.

What matters is that `foo1.id()` is invoked before the call to `emplace`, which moves from the reference to `foo1` provided by `std::move`. That is the case - function calls are always sequenced after the evaluation of their arguments.

This code is safe as long as `id()` returns a value, not a reference to something that might be destroyed or invalidated by the move.

Comment: Is there any guarantee on the order of evaluation of the function arguments, or can they be arbitrary?

Comment: @vigs1990: The order isn't specified.

Comment: Wasn't there a proposal to guarantee the order of evaluation floating around?

Comment: @Morwenn: wouldn't be surprised if some nong somewhere had suggested it, but such a proposal would have very little chance of being accepted: C/C++ have very deliberately left it up to the optimiser to arrange the evaluation as best it can, and such a fundamental change would be quite restrictive (e.g. register allocation, CPU pipeline optimisation, extra memory barriers updating atomics etc.).

Comment: @TonyD [I found it](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4228.pdf). A paper from 2014 by Gabriel Dos Rei, Herb Sutter and Jonathan Caves.

Comment: @Morwenn: thanks for digging it out - an amusing read - I'd hazard that "...to unspecified order of evaluation has been discovered only recently by a tool..." is the most telling thing in there, and points not to the practical importance of mandating evaluation order, but to the utility of improved compiler warnings for accesses that might happen before or after mutating (non-`const`) operations.  Much less work for compiler writers, and optionally slowing your compile by a few percent every now and then is far more palatable than something similar for your executable every time it runs.